# Real power series absolutely converges. Does complex series converge too?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Consider a function $f: (0,1) \to \mathbb R$ defined as the following power series:
$$
f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k (1-x)^k.
$$
This series has $a_k > 0$ and is assumed to converge point-wise for all $x \in (0,1)$.

My **question** is:

If $x$ in the above expression is replaced by a complex variable $z$, can it be assured that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k (1-z)^k$ converges for all $z$ with $|z-1|<1$?

Here is my **attempt at a proof**, but I'm not sure it is correct.

The series for $x \in (0,1)$ is absolutely convergent in $(0,1)$ by the assumptions. That is, $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k (1-x)^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k |1-x|^k$ is finite for all such $x$. Replacing $x$ by any complex $z$ such that $|1-z| = |1-x|$, the resulting $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k |1-z|^k$ converges to the same value. This implies that the complex series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k (1-z)^k$ (absolutely) converges. Since this holds for any $x \in (0,1)$, the complex series converges for any $z$ in the disk $|z-1|<1$.

Are all my steps **correct**? If so, is there any **shorter proof**? If not, is there a **counterexample**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The steps are correct. Perhaps you can simplify notation by considering the series $\Sigma_{k=0}^\infty a_ky^k$. It has a radius of convergence $R$; this means that $\Sigma_{k=0}^\infty a_ky^k$ converges absolutely for $\lvert y \rvert < R$ and diverges for $\lvert y \rvert > R$. You know that it converges for $0 < y  < 1$; this is possible only when $1 \le R$. The complex series $\Sigma_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k$ has the same radius $R$ of convergence as the real series.